# Record audio in Android

Tags: android

How to put on pause? I have not found such a function. There are other ways?

Answer (score 0):

You can try MediaRecorder class available in Android. It has options to start and stop your recording

```
MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
 recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
 recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
 recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
 recorder.setOutputFile(PATH_NAME);
 recorder.prepare();
 recorder.start();   // Recording is now started
 ...
 recorder.stop();
 recorder.reset();   // You can reuse the object by going back to setAudioSource() step
 recorder.release(); // Now the object cannot be reused
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html

Comment: This I know. How to put on pause?

Comment: As far as i know we don't have a pause functionality for MediaRecorder class. You can only stop and start it